# Difference between allowNull and require in sequelize

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

What is the difference between `allowNull=false` and `require=true` in [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)?

Comment: I don't think there is a require option when defining a table. Where are you getting require=true from? allowNull=false means the column must have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Both `required:true` and `allowNull:false` means the same for the sequelize ORM.

In general `required:true` is used for MongoDB(*mongoose*)
and `allowNull:false` by sequelize.

For Sequelize both will work.